# How to properly show a window after clicking on a notification?

Tags: python, pyqt, notifications, gnome, dbus

I'm wondering what's the proper way to show my window after clicking on a notification?

This is what I've tried:

```py
def callback(*_):
    mainWindow.show()
    mainWindow.raise_() 
    mainWindow.activateWindow()

notification.addAction('default', '', callback) #notification sent using dbus
notification.show()
```

But it has a undesired behaviour:
when clicking on the notification, the notification center (I'm on Gnome) stays open on top of my window.

Reproducible example:

```py
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import dbus
from collections import OrderedDict


#   Copyright (c) 2018 Kurt Jacobson
#      <kurtcjacobson@gmail.com>
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
DBusGMainLoop = None
try:
    from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
except:
    print ("Could not import DBusGMainLoop, is package 'python-dbus.mainloop.glib' installed?")

APP_NAME = 'test'
DBUS_IFACE = None
NOTIFICATIONS = {}

class Urgency:
    """freedesktop.org notification urgency levels"""
    LOW, NORMAL, CRITICAL = range(3)

class UninitializedError(RuntimeError):
    """Error raised if you try to show an error before initializing"""
    pass

def init():
    """Initializes the DBus connection"""
    global DBUS_IFACE

    name = "org.freedesktop.Notifications"
    path = "/org/freedesktop/Notifications"
    interface = "org.freedesktop.Notifications"

    mainloop = None
    if DBusGMainLoop is not None:
        mainloop = DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

    bus = dbus.SessionBus(mainloop)
    proxy = bus.get_object(name, path)
    DBUS_IFACE = dbus.Interface(proxy, interface)

    if mainloop is not None:
        # We have a mainloop, so connect callbacks
        DBUS_IFACE.connect_to_signal('ActionInvoked', _onActionInvoked)
        DBUS_IFACE.connect_to_signal('NotificationClosed', _onNotificationClosed)

def _onActionInvoked(nid, action):
    """Called when a notification action is clicked"""
    nid, action = int(nid), str(action)
    try:
        notification = NOTIFICATIONS[nid]
    except KeyError:
        # must have been created by some other program
        return
    notification._onActionInvoked(action)

def _onNotificationClosed(nid, reason):
    """Called when the notification is closed"""
    nid, reason = int(nid), int(reason)
    try:
        notification = NOTIFICATIONS[nid]
    except KeyError:
        # must have been created by some other program
        return
    notification._onNotificationClosed(notification)
    del NOTIFICATIONS[nid]

class Notification(object):
    """Notification object"""

    id = 0
    timeout = -1
    _onNotificationClosed = lambda *args: None

    def __init__(self, title, body='', icon='', timeout=-1):
        """Initializes a new notification object.

        Args:
            title (str):              The title of the notification
            body (str, optional):     The body text of the notification
            icon (str, optional):     The icon to display with the notification
            timeout (TYPE, optional): The time in ms before the notification hides, -1 for default, 0 for never
        """

        self.title = title              # title of the notification
        self.body = body                # the body text of the notification
        self.icon = icon                # the path to the icon to use
        self.timeout = timeout          # time in ms before the notification disappears
        self.hints = {}                 # dict of various display hints
        self.actions = OrderedDict()    # actions names and their callbacks
        self.data = {}                  # arbitrary user data

    def show(self):
        if DBUS_IFACE is None:
            raise UninitializedError("You must call 'notify.init()' before 'notify.show()'")

        """Asks the notification server to show the notification"""
        nid = DBUS_IFACE.Notify(APP_NAME,
                           self.id,
                           self.icon,
                           self.title,
                           self.body,
                           self._makeActionsList(),
                           self.hints,
                           self.timeout,
                        )

        self.id = int(nid)

        NOTIFICATIONS[self.id] = self
        return True

    def close(self):
        """Ask the notification server to close the notification"""
        if self.id != 0:
            DBUS_IFACE.CloseNotification(self.id)

    def onClosed(self, callback):
        """Set the callback called when the notification is closed"""
        self._onNotificationClosed = callback

    def addAction(self, action, label, callback, user_data=None):
        """Add an action to the notification.

        Args:
            action (str):               A sort key identifying the action
            label (str):                The text to display on the action button
            callback (bound method):    The method to call when the action is activated
            user_data (any, optional):  Any user data to be passed to the action callback
        """
        self.actions[action] = (label, callback, user_data)

    def _makeActionsList(self):
        """Make the actions array to send over DBus"""
        arr = []
        for action, (label, callback, user_data) in self.actions.items():
            arr.append(action)
            arr.append(label)
        return arr

    def _onActionInvoked(self, action):
        """Called when the user activates a notification action"""
        try:
            label, callback, user_data = self.actions[action]
        except KeyError:
            return

        if user_data is None:
            callback(self, action)
        else:
            callback(self, action, user_data)
            
def window():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   widget = QWidget()

   button = QPushButton("Notify", widget)
   button.move(110,85)
   def button_callback():
    notification = Notification("Test")
    def notification_callback(*_):
        widget.show()
        widget.raise_() 
        widget.activateWindow()
        notification.close()
    notification.addAction("default", "", notification_callback)
    notification.show()
   button.clicked.connect(button_callback)

   widget.setGeometry(50,50,320,200)
   widget.setWindowTitle("My Window")
   widget.show()
   init()
   sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

Basically when I click the notification, my callback function runs, the notification is dismissed, but the notifications list remains open. Probably I'm not requesting focus correctly...

Comment: The issue should be that the notification should close?

Comment: Yeah, the notification center (or whatever it's called) is closed when I click on notification from other apps, like Firefox or Geary.

Comment: You may need to return something from the callback, but right now it's difficult to know that, as we don't have any clue about what is `notification`. Please provide more details or a [mre].

Comment: Presumably, the notifications are part of some gnome-specific system based on the [Desktop Notifications Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/notification-spec/notification-spec-latest.html). But what python package is being used to interact with these notifications via dbus?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've just added an example.

Comment: @ekhumoro yep, the freedesktop specification is used.

Comment: This seems to be the default behavior of gnome. I noticed it also happens to their Settings app.